# How do I set reference time python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

Hello I want to check if the time `A` that I have in my dataset is night or day

```
import datetime
A
   datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 12, 12, 39, 58)
if  A < datetime.time(19):
    print 'day'
else:
    print 'night'
```

but I get the following error and I don't understand why

```
TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Comment: When you post code and an error message, make sure the code you post is the actual code that produced the error message. That `TypeError` indicates that you didn't actually import `datetime` the way your posted code does it.

Comment: you need *two* times (when it starts; when it ends). See [Python - Working out if time now is between two times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20518122/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_cycle(dt):
    return "day" if 6 <= dt.hour < 19 else "night"
```

this would define day as anything between 6am and 7pm as daytime

if you wanted more flexibility

```
def get_cycle(dt):
    day_start = datetime.time(6,35) # day starts at 6:35am
    day_end = datetime.time(17,45) #day ends at 5:45pm
    return "day" if day_start <= dt.time() < day_end else "night"
```

Comment: Use half-closed interval: `start <= dt.hour < end` i.e., include the start time so that it is equivalent to: `dt.hour in range(start, end)`. See [option a) described by Dijkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
if A.hour < 19:
    print 'day'
else:
    print 'night'
```

But this will end up counting 19 out of 24 possible hours as daytime, which does not seem correct.