# Check current time is between two times

Tags: date, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am trying to check if the current time if between two predermined times and that the day is Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday. Something like:

```
if day = monday, tuesday, wednesday or thursday
   if current_time > 6:00 PM and current_time < 6:15 PM
      then do something
```

Here is what I have so far, the only bit left is setting the two times I want to check between:

```
weekday = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
hour = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())

if weekday < 5:
    if hour
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`datetime.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) method and attributes: [`datetime.hour`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.hour) and [`datetime.minute`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.minute).

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if now.weekday() < 5 and now.hour == 18 and 0 <= now.minute <= 15:
    do_something()
```

Comment: use `now.weekday() < calendar.FRIDAY` otherwise Friday (`==4`) is included. To support start/end time with different hours, see [`in_between()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33681543/4279)