# How to filter a list containing dates according to the given start date and end date?

Tags: python, list

With the following data:

```
dates = ['4/6/2013', '5/4/2013', '6/26/2013', '7/26/2013', '9/5/2013', '10/7/2013',
         '10/12/2013', '4/12/2014', '5/10/2014', '6/12/2014', '7/19/2014', '8/15/2014',
         '9/17/2014', '4/21/2015', '5/28/2015', '6/26/2015']
```

If user selects `start date = 1/1/2014` and end `date = 12/31/2014`
the desired output should be:

```
dates = ['4/12/2014', '5/10/2014', '6/12/2014', '7/19/2014', '8/15/2014', '9/17/2014']
```

I am new to Python. I wrote some code but can't make it work. Please suggest me some code.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We generally like it if you write some codes *here*. Codes written somewhere else do not help you with the problem. :)

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464410/how-to-tell-if-a-date-is-between-two-other-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If what you have tried is dealing with dates as strings I would recommend using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Convert your string dates to datetime objects and then just compare all dates in the list with start and end dates:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime.strptime('1/1/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
end_date = datetime.strptime('12/31/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
dates=['4/6/2013', '5/4/2013', '6/26/2013', '7/26/2013', '9/5/2013', '10/7/2013', '10/12/2013', '4/12/2014', '5/10/2014', '6/12/2014', '7/19/2014', '8/15/2014', '9/17/2014', '4/21/2015', '5/28/2015', '6/26/2015']

# this line creates a list of datetime objects from the given strings in list dates
dt_dates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') for date in dates]
```

Now compare with start and end:

```
in_between_dates = []
for d in dt_dates:
    if d >= start_date and d <= end_date:
        in_between_dates.append(d)
```

Here I print the output in the same string format as was given:

```
print [d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for d in in_between_dates]
# prints: ['04/12/2014', '05/10/2014', '06/12/2014', '07/19/2014', '08/15/2014', '09/17/2014']
```

Two main methods in datetime used here are [`strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) used to convert a string to a datetime object and to convert datetime to a string, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt  

st = "1/1/2014"
end = "12/31/2014"

# returns True if d1 is smaller than d2
def is_smaller(d1, d2):
  return dt.strptime(d1, "%m/%d/%Y") < dt.strptime(d2, "%m/%d/%Y")

# returns True if date is in between st and end
def filter_func(date):
  return is_smaller(st, date) and is_smaller(date, end)

dates=['4/6/2013', '5/4/2013', '6/26/2013', '7/26/2013', '9/5/2013', '10/7/2013', '10/12/2013', '4/12/2014', '5/10/2014', '6/12/2014', '7/19/2014', '8/15/2014', '9/17/2014', '4/21/2015', '5/28/2015', '6/26/2015']

print(list(filter(filter_func, dates)))
```

I have just given you the idea. Now, you can modify this according to your needs. Find more information about [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library to convert your date strings into datetime objects so they can be compared. Then you can simply use list comprehension to produce a list of the required dates.

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>start_date = datetime.strptime('1/1/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>>end_date = datetime.strptime('12/31/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
>>>dates=['4/6/2013', '5/4/2013', '6/26/2013', '7/26/2013', '9/5/2013', '10/7/2013', '10/12/2013', '4/12/2014', '5/10/2014', '6/12/2014', '7/19/2014', '8/15/2014', '9/17/2014', '4/21/2015', '5/28/2015', '6/26/2015']
>>>gooddates = [i for i in dates if start_date < datetime.strptime(i, '%m/%d/%Y') <end_date]

['4/12/2014', '5/10/2014', '6/12/2014', '7/19/2014', '8/15/2014', '9/17/2014']
```