# How to filter a specific year's rows from a list of datetime.datetime objects?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

For example if I have a list like: `[datetime.datetime(2016,5,1), datetime.datetime(2015,2,5)]`
and I want 2015 entries filtered out from that list.

Consider this list consists of many entries for the example I put in only two entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I filter a python list containing dates according to the given start date and end date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375873/how-do-i-filter-a-python-list-containing-dates-according-to-the-given-start-date)

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the `year` attribute:

```
>>> some_dates = [datetime.datetime(2016,5,1), datetime.datetime(2015,2,5)]
>>> [x for x in some_dates if x.year != 2015]
[datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter get filtered list with

```
lst=[datetime.datetime(2016,5,1),datetime.datetime(2015,2,5)]
filtered_list = [date for date in lst if date.year == 2015]
```

filtered_list is :

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 5, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very long list of dates, skipping the ones undesired could be done iteratively using the built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function in Python 3, or the [`itertools.ifilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) in Python 2.

In either case, creating a second—potentially also very long—list is avoided.

```
import datetime
try:
    from itertools import ifilter
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    ifilter = filter

dates = [datetime.datetime(2016,5,1), datetime.datetime(2015,2,5)]

for date in ifilter(lambda d: d.year != 2015, dates):
    # do something with non-2015 date...
    print(date)  # -> 2016-05-01 00:00:00
```