# How to check if date is between two dates in python

Tags: python

How to check if a date is between two dates in python?

EDIT1: In excel, the date that I am reading is 7/13/2018 for example.

Comment: Give example of date format that you are using.

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: Duplicate of [How to tell if a date is between two other dates in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464410/how-to-tell-if-a-date-is-between-two-other-dates-in-python).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a date is between two other dates in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464410/how-to-tell-if-a-date-is-between-two-other-dates-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert the date so it can be easily compared in Python. Dates 1 and 2 are the converted dates, `input_1` and `input_2` are the two inputs from Excel. The second parameter passed in is the format in which the date is passed in.

```
date_1 = datetime.strptime(input_1, '%d/%m/%Y')
date_2 = datetime.strptime(input_2, '%d/%m/%Y')
date_3 = date(2017, 7, 19)
```

Now that you have the dates in the right format, I will check if `date_3` falls within `date_1` and `date_2`. This will return a Boolean.

```
date_1 < date_3 < date_2
```